# dovecot-lmtp does not exist

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I followed [this guide on linode](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql) to setup dovecot and postfix mail server on my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS . The setup requires socket `/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp` to act as virtual transport. However, in my setup, this socket file doesn't exist when the service is started. And I do have the `lmtp` line in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`.

Here's a little info about my server.

```
Linux prosp 3.8.4-linode50 #1 SMP Mon Mar 25 15:50:29 EDT 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

root@prosp:/var/spool/postfix/private# ls
anvil   bsmtp    dovecot-auth  lmtp      mailman     relay    scache             tlsmgr      verify
auth    defer    error         local     proxymap    retry    scalemail-backend  trace   virtual
bounce  discard  ifmail        maildrop  proxywrite  rewrite  smtp               uucp

root@prosp:/var/spool/postfix/private# aptitude show postfix postfix-mysql dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d dovecot-lmtpd dovecot-mysql
Package: postfix
State: installed
Version: 2.9.6-1~12.04.1

Package: postfix-mysql
State: installed
Version: 2.9.6-1~12.04.1

Package: dovecot-core
State: installed
Version: 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2

Package: dovecot-imapd
State: installed
Version: 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2

Package: dovecot-pop3d
State: installed
Version: 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2

Package: dovecot-lmtpd
State: installed
Version: 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2

Package: dovecot-mysql
State: installed
Version: 1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2
```

Section from 10-master.conf

```
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
  # Create inet listener only if you can't use the above UNIX socket
  inet_listener lmtp {
    # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
    address = 127.0.0.1
    port = 2424
  }
}
```

I'm wondering why it doesn't exist. I've tried reinstalling dovecot-lmtpd to no avail. And because the lmtp socket doesn't exist, my mail server can send emails but cannot receive. The mail log has this line when an incoming email is received:

```
May 31 09:05:24 postfix/lmtp[3664]: 2FD80321F4: to=<myaddress@me.com>, relay=none, delay=0.41, delays=0.41/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to me.com[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
```

Logs after dovecot is restarted:

```
May 31 11:38:10 host dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 31 11:38:10 host dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 31 11:38:10 host dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.0.19 starting up (core dumps disabled)
May 31 11:38:11 host postfix/smtpd[5741]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
May 31 11:38:11 host dovecot: auth-worker: mysql(127.0.0.1): Connected to database mailserver
May 31 11:38:11 host postfix/smtpd[5741]: 3F8A24DE2A3: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=info@mydomain.com
May 31 11:38:11 host postfix/cleanup[5751]: 3F8A24DE2A3: message-id=<20130531113811.3F8A24DE2A3@otherdomain.com>
May 31 11:38:11 host postfix/qmgr[5683]: 3F8A24DE2A3: from=<info@mydomain.com>, size=938, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 31 11:38:11 host postfix/smtpd[5741]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
May 31 11:38:11 host postfix/error[5753]: 3F8A24DE2A3: to=<heshiming@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to otherdomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
```

Any ideas why this have happened?

It looks like I can't use lmtp as an inet listener either:

```
May 31 12:22:48 host postfix/lmtp[6798]: connect to localhost[127.0.0.1]:2424: Connection refused
May 31 12:22:48 host postfix/lmtp[6798]: connect to localhost[::1]:2424: Connection refused
May 31 12:22:48 host postfix/lmtp[6799]: connect to localhost[127.0.0.1]:2424: Connection refused
May 31 12:22:48 host postfix/lmtp[6799]: connect to localhost[::1]:2424: Connection refused
```

Comment: Do you have this: `service lmtp {
 unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
   mode = 0600
   user = postfix
   group = postfix
  }` in this `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf` ?

Comment: If you do, do you have errors in the pertinent log files when you start dovecot?

Comment: @NickW I do have the lmtp section. When dovecot is restarted, it produces thousands of the 'no such file or directory' error in the log. I guess this is because mails are actually received but not delivered. Besides these errors, I'm not seeing anything particular. My problem though, is that I really don't have this executable file.

Comment: Can you paste in the errors from the first 10-20 lines after the restart?

Comment: I've appended the log at the end of this post.

Comment: Hmm, not much there, do you have lmtp in the protocols line in dovecot.conf?

Comment: I do have this protocol. Actually I've copied the config file from the guide. I'll review the log file again to see why this socket is not created.

Comment: It is awfully odd, especially considering there is an `lmtp` and a `dovecot-auth` file, so it does seem to have the permission to create files..

Comment: The other services are all up, including imap, authentication via mysql, pop, smtp. The folder is owned by postfix. The time of other sockets are exactly the service restart time. Only this lmtp transport is broken. And regarding the log, the errors are produced when postfix is restarted, dovecot restart produces no errors.

Comment: I'm going hazard a guess and say you may have some syntax error in `10-master.conf`, can you post the whole service lmtp section?

Comment: The file is actually identical to https://library.linode.com/assets/1240-dovecot_10-master.conf.txt with the exception that I opened 110 port. I now have tried switching it to inet listener, but it still failed to work.

Comment: If you use the inet listener, you'll need to change the postfix virtual transport line from unix: to inet: (I think)

Comment: I've done that and I've updated the post. That's why postfix is looking for lmtp at port 2424, but it's not opened regardless of the lmtp section dovecot config.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9029/discussion-between-nickw-and-he-shiming)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/622978/dovecot-lmtp-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 12):

The answers and responses already given contain all the parts of the solution, here's my attempt to tie that info together, having struggled with and now fixed the same problem:

**Overview**: Dovecot only acts upon the `service lmtp` section if `lmtp` appears in the `protocols` setting. Especially if you have a custom `dovecot.conf` file you may have omitted something.

**Detail** (for Debian, and by extension Ubuntu): Here's the key steps,

- `apt-get install dovecot-lmtpd`
- Check that `dovecot.conf` (in `/etc/dovecot`) includes the line `!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol`: This is where `protocols` is set (specifically the `lmtp.protocol` file contains `protocols = $protocols lmtp`
- Now to the `service lmtp` section: This should be in `conf.d/10-master.conf` but may be empty; the original question has settings in this section (adjust accordingly if you're doing the same thing):

  ```
  service lmtp {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
      mode = 0600
      user = postfix
      group = postfix
    }
  }
  ```
- Make sure that the above `conf.d/10-master.conf` is included by your `dovecot.conf` (typically with `!include conf.d/*.conf`)
- Reload Dovecot (`service dovecot reload`) for this configuration change to take effect
- Double-check the running configuration with `dovecot -n`: Check that `protocols` is set and includes `lmtp`; check that the above `service lmtp` stanza appears too.
- If you're specifying the `dovecot-lmtp` socket name as above, it should now exist (that `service ltmp` stanza tells Dovecot to create it when running), check with `ls -l /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp`
- This should now play nicely with Postfix.

Comment: This worked for me... ubuntu 16

Comment: In my case, I borrowed the default configuration block which lacked ''/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp'' and instead only had ''lmtp'' so it kept pitching a doesn't exist error since I did not specify the full path, nor the actual location. Thanks, oemb1905.

Answer (score 5):

I've discovered that though I have `protocols = lmtp pop3 imap` in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`, it's overridden by `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf` which contains only `protocols = pop3 imap sieve`. I've modified this file and the lmtp protocol is up.

Comment: You can check to make sure no other files have the `protocols =` line using `sudo grep -rnw '/etc/dovecot/' -e "protocols ="`

Comment: this solved my problem, but it seems like a dirty solution. is there a cleaner way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

https://packages.debian.org/sid/dovecot-lmtpd

apt-get install dovecot-lmtpd

Comment: Please add more details ...

Comment: Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's very interesting thing. I've done all the things I read here. In my private directory is a

```
/var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp
```

but no

```
/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
```

so the postfix tell me:

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: It works for me. In ubuntu 18.04 is /var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp