# dovecot-lmtp: No such file or directory)

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a problem w/ dovecot

```
[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
```

Idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[SOLVED]** It seems this entry only in /etc/postfix/main.cf applies to Ubuntu/Debian systems.

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

change in

```
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Comment: it said "mail transport unavailable" for me...

Comment: More detail on what's going on [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/512219/dovecot-lmtp-does-not-exist/784154#784154) (my answer to a similar question)

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a very old post, but I had the same problem today, and I can't find the right solution, but a lot of "tips&tricks" :)

I solved myself:

- Ubuntu Server 14.04
- Modoboa 1.6.0
- Postfix, Dovecot, ecc..

The problem was in the file `/etc/dovecot/local.conf` in the line protocols
there was no LMTP protocol listed so adding LMTP and restarting Dovecot solved my problem.

from:

```
protocols = imap
```

to:

```
protocols = imap lmtp
```

Answer (score 3):

This error could be caused also if the package `dovecot-lmtpd` isn't installed.

Comment: this solution worked for me +1