# postfix dovecot lmtp status=deferred (connect to domain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

I'm setting up my own Ubuntu mail server at home (postfix-mysql-dovecot-roundcube) with a MX registered domain (here in my example it will be "domain.com").

My main.cf :

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname Welcome
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

relayhost =
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = domain.com
alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 5368709120
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_protocols = ipv4
inet_interfaces = all
queue_directory = /mail/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT" -d "$USER"
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_mailbox_base = /mail/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
milter_default_action = accept
```

master.cf :

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd

pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil

scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

I've defined all the other files for postfix-mysql and dovecot, following some online tutorials.
I can receive external emails but they are stuck in the postix queue. When I try to retrieve them, I get these log lines :

```
May 16 11:03:36 mail postfix/qmgr[4236]: 719CE44008A: from=<jerome@other-domain.com>, size=2220, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 16 11:03:36 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[22152]: warning: do not list domain domain.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
May 16 11:03:36 mail postfix/lmtp[22153]: 719CE44008A: to=<helje@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=50625, delays=50625/0.14/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to domain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
```

Any idea ?

Here is the dovecot main config file (dovecot.conf) :

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_gid = 8 # mail group gid
first_valid_uid = 150 # vmail user uid
listen = *
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = vmail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@domain.com
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster@domain.com
}
protocol lda {
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
```

The dovecot-sql.conf.ext config file :

```
# This file is commonly accessed via passdb {} or userdb {} section in
# conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext

# This file is opened as root, so it should be owned by root and mode 0600.
#
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL
#
# Database driver: mysql, pgsql, sqlite
driver = mysql

connect = host=db dbname=mail_db user=usermail password=password

default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT

password_query = SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u'

user_query = SELECT '/mail/vmail/%d/%n' as home, 150 AS uid, 8 AS gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u'

# If you wish to avoid two SQL lookups (passdb + userdb), you can use
# userdb prefetch instead of userdb sql in dovecot.conf. In that case you'll
# also have to return userdb fields in password_query prefixed with "userdb_"
# string. For example:
#password_query = \
#  SELECT userid AS user, password, \
#    home AS userdb_home, uid AS userdb_uid, gid AS userdb_gid \
#  FROM users WHERE userid = '%u'

# Query to get a list of all usernames.
#iterate_query = SELECT username AS user FROM mailbox
```

The dovecot server status :

```
dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since lun. 2016-05-16 17:52:28 CEST; 1min 42s ago
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)
           http://wiki2.dovecot.org/
  Process: 4624 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4627 (dovecot)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
           ├─4627 /usr/sbin/dovecot
           ├─4629 dovecot/anvil
           ├─4630 dovecot/log
           └─4632 dovecot/config

mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net dovecot[4624]: Error: systemd listens on port 143, but it's not configured in Dovecot. Closing.
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net dovecot[4624]: master: Error: systemd listens on port 143, but it's not configured in Dovecot. Closing.
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net dovecot[4624]: Error: systemd listens on port 993, but it's not configured in Dovecot. Closing.
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net dovecot[4624]: master: Error: systemd listens on port 993, but it's not configured in Dovecot. Closing.
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net systemd[1]: dovecot.service: PID file /var/run/dovecot/master.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net dovecot[4627]: master: Dovecot v2.2.22 (fe789d2) starting up for lmtp, imap (core dumps disabled)
mai 16 17:52:28 mail.lidric.net systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
```

Comment: In what way is `do not list domain domain.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains` not clear as to what change needs to be done?

Comment: Please [edit] your question as appropriate instead of replying in comment.

Comment: Looks like dovecot is not running or misconfigured.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/512219/dovecot-lmtp-does-not-exist

Comment: Thanks Alexus but that case didn't help, different from mine :)

Comment: Is  `/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp` exist,?